# Scala unpickling from string

Tags: scala, scala-pickling

I tried the following Unit Test.

First test `testUnpickleJsonPickleFormat` works well. It pickles a String and unpickle the pickle.

`testUnpickleString{1,2}` tests to unserialize a String. But they don't work at all. I don't know where something miss me.

```
import org.junit.Test

import scala.pickling._
import scala.pickling.json._

class PicklerTest {

  @Test
  def testUnpickleJsonPickleFormat {
    val src = "elem 1"
    val pckl = src.pickle
    val res = pckl.unpickle[String]
    println(src)
    println(pckl.toString +"\n")
    println(res)
  }

  @Test
  def testUnpickleString1 {
    val json = """JSONPickle({
                 |      "tpe": "java.lang.String",
                 |      "value": "elem 1"
                 |    })""".stripMargin.trim
    val pckl = JSONPickle(json.toString)
    val res = pckl.unpickle[String]

  }

  @Test
  def testUnpickleString2 {
    val src = "elem 1"
    val pckl = src.pickle
    val pckl2 = JSONPickle(pckl.toString)
    val res = pckl2.unpickle[String]
    println(src)
    println(pckl.toString +"\n")
    println(res)
  }
}
```

I don't know how to use unpickle with the Scala Pickle framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use

```
{
  "tpe": "java.lang.String",
  "value": "elem 1"
}
```

without `JSONPickle(...)`:

```
val json = """{
  "tpe": "java.lang.String",
  "value": "elem 1"
}"""

JSONPickle(json).unpickle[String]
// String = elem 1
```

`JSONPickle({...})` is not a valid `JSON`.

You should also use `pckl.value` instead of `pckl.toString` to get `JSON` without `JSONPickle(...)`:

```
val src = "elem 1"
val pckl = src.pickle
val pckl2 = JSONPickle(pckl.value)
pckl2.unpickle[String]
// String = elem 1
```

You could also use pattern matching like this:

```
val src = "elem 2"
val pckl = src.pickle
val pckl2 = pckl match {
  case JSONPickle(value) => JSONPickle(value)
} 
pckl2.unpickle[String]
// String = elem 2
```